# Error TS2322 en declarar constante route en Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap

estoy aprendiendo a usar angular, pero cuando quiero declara una constante de rutas me marca un error que dice así:

> Type '{ path: string; component: typeof HomeComponent; }' is not
> assignable to type 'Route'.   Object literal may only specify known
> properties, and 'path' does not exist in type 'Route'.ts(2322)

Mi codigo es asi:

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FormComponent } from './form/form.component';
import { Route } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
const routes: Route[]=[
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'form', component: FormComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

el error es en esta parte:

```
const routes: Route[]=[
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'form', component: FormComponent}
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas importando el tipo que no es y por eso te sale el error.

Tienes que importar `Route` desde la siguiente ubicación.

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: Es correcto, muchas gracias.